# Audi A4 B9 oil for automatic transmission

Tags: automatic-transmission, audi

I want to change the oil on a Audi A4 B9 2015 2.0TDI 150HP FWD automatic transmission.
How many liters go into automatic transmission and what type?
I received the owner's manual in german but it is not specified anywhere how many liters or the type of oil for automatic gearbox or engine.

Comment: I'm not sure on your model, but newer Audi's have a strange transmission oil change procedure. It DEFINITELY is not straight forward. If you don't know what you're doing, I'd highly recommend you take it to someone who can do it.

Comment: Just wondering if you have checked your Owner's Manual?  Often both the type and quantity of fluids are listed.

Comment: I don't have the manual. I bought it second hand with 120.000km on board.

Comment: I know that at 90.000km the oil had to be changed. The previous owner said he didn't change it.

Comment: If it's like other Audi's I've written articles on, you have to have it on a lift in order to do the change and get the level correct. The vehicle has to be completely level or you'll get it wrong. Just saying, this is probably something I would not attempt at home, and I'll do most any work except machining and differential gear sets.

Comment: Ok i will go to an authorized service but i would like to know how many liters enter in automatic transmission because in my area in service the mechanics inflate the price of labor and spare parts.

Comment: @tt177 You can find online copies of all Audi Owner's Manuals at: http://ownersmanual.audiusa.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automatic transmisson model : `DL382-7F S-TRONIC`

- oil change at 60000 km or 5 years
- filling capacity 7 litres
- original oil G055529A2 or an example of after market oil Ravenol RAVATF DCT/DSG
- oil filter and gasket

Total labor and after market materials cost around 250 euros.